# Laravel change main page after login

Tags: php, laravel

I would like show other main page after login to the user.

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BlogController@getUserBlog');
});
```

When user is log in I would like to show `BlogController@getUserBlog` it's working but, when user is not authenticated laravel shows `/login` page not `PagesController@getIndex`. How to correct this for:

Auth user: `BlogController@getUserBlog`

Guest: `PagesController@getIndex`

Comment: It can be done in many ways. Like you can check if user is logged in and then redirect them to different pages from `getUserBlog` method in `BlogController`. If you want to do it from route, you have to do same. First check if user is logged in or not and send to specific page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can do it without middleware :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function()
{
    if ( Auth::check() )
    {
        Route::get('/', 'BlogController@getUserBlog');
    } else{
        Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
    }
});
```

Comment: For non login user shows getUserBlog, not working correctly.

Comment: are you sure? without adding anything in the routes file just the lines above ?

Comment: Yes, I put this code on the end of web.php, I check this and `if(Auth::check())` doesn't work, but user is log in.

Comment: `var_dump(Auth::id())` returns NULL in web.php file

Comment: try `var_dump(Auth::guest());` !!

Comment: Returns true when user is log in

Comment: Try to add `Route::group(['prefix' => '/', 'middleware' => 'web']` , function ...` and re-test !!

Answer (score 3):

Make changes in this Middleware [`RedirectIfAuthenticated`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //Logged In
        return redirect()->route('getUserBlog');
    }

    // Not Logged In
    return redirect()->route('getIndex');
}
```

and make the necessary change in your `routes` file

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex')->name('getIndex');
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@getUserBlog')->name('getUserBlog');
```

Comment: For non login user shows getUserBlog, not working correctly.